# Alternative ContextMenuStrip

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to be able to change the style of the ContextMenuStrip currently available in .NET, I've always found it very ugly.

For example, this is the one in the Framework:

[image]

And I would like to use this system-style menu in my program:

[image]

Is there any way I can use the normal context strip in a managed app?

Comment: Why not use the basic `ContextMenu`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the old [ContextMenu](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenu.aspx) control, e.g.

```
ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu();
menu.MenuItems.Add("Hello");
menu.MenuItems.Add("-"); // yes, this makes a separator !!!
menu.MenuItems.Add("World");
```

Image:

[image]